# how to find the argument of a multipication of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know how to find Arg(z).
I'm having problem with the following expression:
$$Arg((\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+ \frac{i}{2})^{16}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i)^{10})$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you may rewrite this as trig functions and then as exponentials:
$$\left(\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})\right)^{16}\left(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{4})\right)^{10}$$
$$=\left(e^{i\pi/6}\right)^{16}\left(e^{-i\pi/4}\right)^{10}$$
$$=e^{8i\pi/3}\cdot e^{-5i\pi/2} $$
$$=e^{i\pi/6}=\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Since $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}=\cos \frac{\pi}{6}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i=\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ we have, from De Moivre's formula
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)^{16}=\cos \frac{16\pi}{6}+i\sin \frac{16\pi}{6}=\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i\right)^{10}=\cos \left(-\frac{10\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin \left(-\frac{10\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$